# material preview displays objects in black although it has texture

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I'm following Lynda's tutorial and I've encountered something that I don't know how to fix.
some of my objects appear in black while I'm in material preview on the layout panel but has no problem on texture painting layout or render view.
im sure its something simple but i have no clow what to do

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try recalculating the normals, or inverting them! Or create a new picture, in the UV Editing window, and change the color from black to another!

Answer (score 0):

The texture has its own color, the material has its own! When you switch display / shader modes, you can see, the only color, which you assigned to the material / texture. Recolor the black background, of the face your mesh, in the editor window, to a color identical to the material!